# Im having trouble centering menu items in footer due to "flexbox"

Tags: menus, css, footer

New to WordPress development, long-time user though. Developing my own site. Have a rudimentary understanding of HTML / CSS.

I'm using 2020 / twenty-twenty theme (child) and the main problem I'm having is when I resize the browser window the text does not act very responsive and just goes weird at one point: This is due to the Flexbox property.

How do I eliminate / offset Flexbox in the Additional CSS? If there's no way to do so there, then what would be the correct way of tackling this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It may not be possible to answer this question based on the information provided alone. It also appears that this might be a question about CSS rather than WordPress, in which case it might be considered off-topic here. It is not clear how the image relates to the problem described, nor how you are associating "the text not acting very responsive and going weird" with flexbox. TwentyTwenty looks perfectly fine responsively, to me - have you made some other modifications which are conflicting with the default styles in order to produce this effect?

Comment: If you have created a child theme, I'd also recommend against using "Additional CSS" - just put the styles in the child theme's stylesheets. IIRC "Additional CSS" rules can be lost when switching themes - but I might be misremembering that.

Comment: Hi Bosco. Yes, the theme itself is responsive but I had massive trouble centering the footer text. I ended up hiding it the additional CSS and used Themify to create a centred footer.   Thank you for the tip regarding Child theme % additional CSS: will try to keep that in mind